# HighCharts For Android Exporting Button

Tags: android, highcharts

I'm using highcharts for android. I wanna change exporting button background. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to add CSS style for the selector `.highcharts-contextbutton highcharts-button-box`. Just like that: 
`.highcharts-contextbutton .highcharts-button-box {
  fill: red;
}`

Comment: It's not web. I use Android library.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the background color of your exporting button, you can use `navigation.buttonOptions.theme.fill` property. Here is how to implement it using our Android wrapper:

```
HINavigation navigation = new HINavigation();
navigation.buttonOptions = new HIButtonOptions();
navigation.buttonOptions.theme = new HITheme();
Navigation.buttonOptions.theme.fill = „#ff0000”;
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/android/highcharts/